# Bitbucket git pull and git push give 'Already up to date' and 'Everything up to date' when I can see online 2 more commits on top

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push, git-pull

Bitbucket git pull and git push are giving 'Already up to date' and 'Everything up to date' when I can see online 2 more commits on top

When using gitk I see that remote master is 2 commits below of the real remote master (the one I can see on bitbucket webview). I do a git pull or a git fetch plus the merge and I always get 'Already up to date'.

If I checkout the latest commit I can see on the webview manually and put it in a different branch I can see on Gitk that I'm now on top of master (local and remote) by 2 commits, so I tried to push these 2 commits again and it says 'Everything up to date'

Not really sure what else I can do. Already cloned the repo from scratch again and same thing. Webview all the commits, right after git clone if I do a git status or use gitk the 2 top commits are not there.

The only think I did different compared to what I was doing before is that those 2 commits have tags. May that be the issue?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently those last 2 commits were somewhere other than master in remote. I was not using the right web view so I was seeing all commits and not the master branch ones.

They looked like they were in some detached head state into remote if that's even possible.

What I did was to pull those 2 commits to a local branch and pushed that branch to remote. Then I created a pull request and merged it with master and now master is up to date with everything.